# ViewDidLoad Method doesn't called in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, viewdidload

I have passed the NSMutableDictionary into the FirstClass using custom init method.

Second Class,

```
firstClass = [[FirstClass alloc] initWithFeedData:feedDictionary];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstClasss animated:YES];
```

FirstClass,

```
 - (FirstClass *) initWithFeedData:(NSMutableDictionary *) dataDictionary {
 {
     NSLog(@"%@", dataDictionary);

     [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstClass" owner:self options:nil];

    //[self viewDidLoad]; Without call, ViewDidLoad method doesn't call.

 }

 - (void) viewDidLoad {

      [super viewDidLoad];

      NSLOG(@"Inside View DidLoad"); // This method never calls.
  }
```

In my viewDidLoad method doesn't called, if i call "[self viewDidLoad]" then only, viewDidLoad method works properly. I donno why viewDidLoad method doesn't call directly without calls in another method? Please Help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe because there is no view being loaded?

Comment: Uh, and it's `NSLog` not `NSLOG` as you have it there. What's it a subclass of? I think that `viewDidLoad` only gets called in `UIViewController` subclasses. Don't quote me on that though.

Comment: @Aurum: That's correct. The `viewDidLoad` method is called on the controller when its view has finished loading.

Comment: @Aurum Aquila,Thats NSLOG is Typo. But i have also used to call "     [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstClass" owner:self options:nil];". So how can i call the viewDidLoad into my application?. Is any other possible solution is there? Thanks.

Comment: Look, what you're trying to do is really not good design practice. You should be calling it using initWithNibName and then call a method that passes it the NSDictionary. This seems like one of those questions that's going to go unanswered because it's just too much of a pain to sit and debug it step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `init` method is not correct. It should look something like this:

```
- (id) initWithFeedData:(NSMutableDictionary *) dataDictionary {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    // TODO: do initialisation stuff with dataDictionary
  }

  return self;
}
```

This assumes that `FirstClass` is derived from `UIViewController`.

As long as your NIB file has the same name as your class it should be loaded in automatically -- there's no need for the `loadBundle:` call. Here's what [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says about the `nibName` property:

> If the value of this property is nil
>   and you did not override the loadView
>   method in your custom subclass, the
>   view controller looks for a nib file
>   whose name (without the .nib
>   extension) matches the name of your
>   view controller class.

Answer (score 2):

If you're subclassing a `UIViewController`, which I assume you are since you're expecting `viewDidLoad`, then you should override its designated initialiser, `initWithNibName:bundle:` if you're using a XIB, in which case `viewDidLoad` will be called after the XIB loads. If you're not using a XIB, you should implement the `loadView` method to create your view, and `viewDidLoad` will be called after `loadView` finishes.

Comment: +1, @Jasarien, Thanks for your Answer, i have used grouped table view,by loaded in XIB. So my xib is not loaded for implements the Stephen Darlington answer. But after that i have load my nib file again into the view did load, so that it loaded properly.By using " [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstClass" owner:self options:nil];".

Comment: Actually, you should not need to call the `loadNibNamed:` method with my code. It will looks for a xib file with the same name as the class. See the documentation: "If the value of this property is nil and you did not override the loadView method in your custom subclass, the view controller looks for a nib file whose name (without the .nib extension) matches the name of your view controller class."

Answer (score 1):

@Stephen is right, at the very least you need to rewrite your init statement to return `self`. However, it's much easier and more robust to declare a property on your view controller and pass objects in that manner.

```
FirstClass *firstClass = [[FirstClass alloc] initWithNibNamed:nil];
firstClass.feedDictionary = feedDictionary;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstClasss animated:YES];
[firstClass release];
```

Your `viewDidLoad` method will now be called and your `feedDictionary` will be sitting there, waiting for you.